# Create table and insert using variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to create a table and insert data only changing the variable name.
but instead, it creates a table with the name @myId, and not with the value of the variable.
i also have tried to remove the `` but i got an sql error.

```
set @myId = "tabletest";

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `@myId` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `@myId` (`id`, `position`) VALUES
(1, 1);
```

Comment: I'm sure you don't want quotes around `@myId`; that makes it a literal.

Comment: @TimRoberts i've already tried this, check the image https://i.imgur.com/uBMmCzt.png

Comment: You will not be able to use the user-defined variables as you would expect in that manner. (I've run into the same issue) The documentation says: `User variables are intended to provide data values. They cannot be used directly in an SQL statement as an identifier or as part of an identifier, such as in contexts where a table or database name is expected`

Comment: @PaulT. thank you for the explanation!

Comment: For others that may cross the same, the information in my previous comment can be [found here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not recommending that you do this.  Table names should not be coming from variables.  However, you did ask a valid question and if you were going to do this, you need dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = 'CREATE TABLE @myId (id int(10) NOT NULL, position int(10) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;';
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@myId', 'tabletest');

PREPARE ct FROM @sql;
EXECUTE ct;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE ct;

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO @myId (id, position) VALUES (1, 1);';
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@myId', 'tabletest');

PREPARE st FROM @sql;

EXECUTE st;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
```

You can then execute:

```
SELECT * FROM tabletest;
```

Note that if you wanted to use `@myId` in the `SELECT`, you would need more dynamic SQL:  Yucch!

Usually the right solution is just a table where you insert rows with an identifier.  You can then delete those rows (or invalidate them) if necessary when you are done.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff5a1e/1) is a db<>fiddle.